# Recaptcha on SSL for Webmatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

Recaptcha, webmatrix and SSL problem.

- Website built on Webmatrix 3.
- Hosted on “azurewebsites”
- I understand that there are problems installing recaptcha of SSL.  All Azurewebsites protected by SSL.
- On the Forum, there is nothing specific to Webmatrix and I have been given the RunAround.
- I did the following and it doesn’t work.

  ---

  ### 1-  I used NuGet to install reCaptcha Plugin for Net.

2-  I already got the public and private key and included them at the top of the page containing the form, and on the `_AppStart.cshtml` Page.

3-  At the top of the form I typed the following;

```
@if(showRecaptcha == true){
    if(ReCaptcha.PrivateKey != "6Lc4eOwSAAAAAD8Ne6TuMiK0IMmgcm5VCINO-4lq "){
        <p>@ReCaptcha.GetHtml()</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
    else {
        <p>  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.</p>
    }
}
```

---

4-  Just before the Submit button I placed the following, containing the public key;

```
@ReCaptcha.GetHtml("6Lc4eOwSAAAAANOYL-7mkUrEa9MizES_hBOaaY8s", theme: "blue")

 @if (!captchaMessage.IsEmpty()) 
 {
      <label class="validation-error"  >@captchaMessage</label>
 }
```

---

5-  Just after the “if(IsPost && Validation.IsValid())”,
I placed the following:

```
// Validate the user's captcha answer.  This is the private key.
if (!ReCaptcha.Validate("6Lc4eOwSAAAAAD8Ne6TuMiK0IMmgcm5VCINO-4lq"))           
{
   ModelState.AddError("recaptcha", "Captcha response was not correct");
}
```

---

6-  The Recaptcha widget appears intact on the form but the verification fails, 
because it accepts anything, as if it is not there.

I would really appreciate any help.
Joseph.